# WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy does not work

Tags: spring, spring-security, x-frame-options

I'm using Spring Security 5.1.5.RELEASE and trying to set `ALLOW FROM` to `X-Frame-Options`

I use the `WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy` and pass a list of URLs to white list although the `header` that is sent is `X-Frame-Options: DENY`

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String permittedRoutes [] = {"/", "/register"};

        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                    .disable()
                .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(Arrays.asList("https://google.com"))));

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(permittedRoutes).permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .permitAll()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "fonts.googleapis.com/**", "fonts.gstatic.com/**");
    }
}
```

Any leads?

Comment: Well, /register ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the `WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy`, you have to add the `x-frames-allow-from` parameter (with the origin as value) to your request, see [XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter with WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy doesn't work](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/123):

> **rwinch commented on 21 Oct 2014**
>
> You need to ensure that you have provided the origin using the x-frames-allow-from parameter and that origin must match one of the whitelisted origins.

See also [`WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy#setAllowFromParameterName`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/header/writers/frameoptions/WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy.html#setAllowFromParameterName-java.lang.String-):

> ```java
> public void setAllowFromParameterName(java.lang.String allowFromParameterName)
> ```
>
> Sets the HTTP parameter used to retrieve the value for the origin that is allowed from. The value of the parameter should be a valid URL. The default parameter name is "x-frames-allow-from".

If you want to allow only one origin at all, you could use [`StaticAllowFromStrategy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/header/writers/frameoptions/StaticAllowFromStrategy.html) instead of `WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy`.